# How to fix a scraper iterating over numerous container tags but only outputting one

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, containers

I've built a scraper, and although it appears to be pulling the correct HTML, when I iterate over the container tags it only appears to pull one record. I'm a noob, so I'm hoping I've missed something simple, but a couple hours of research has me stumped.

I've searched for a solution, and I've made sure that it is actually pulling all the HTML I need. When I run this code at the end, however, I only get one result instead of all of them. Same when I export to .csv.

```py
print("product_name: " + product_name)
print("product_number: " + product_number)
print("category: " + category)
```

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```py
containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"Product"})

for container in containers:

    product_name = container.a.text

    product_number = container.div.text

    category_container = container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip()
    category = category_container
```

I would expect to get an output of over 1000 products, but instead I get only one. What am I missing? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you use `print()` ? You have to use it inside `for container in containers:` to see many results.

Comment: I bet that you got the last one since you always overwrite the product in every iteration. You can use `.append()` method. For example, `product_name.append(container.a.text)` to save the `product_name`. Do the same for the others.

Comment: variables `product_name`, `product_number`, `category` can keep only one value - last value from loop. To keep more values you have to use lists and `append()` value to list..

Comment: @furas I was just printing in my Jupyter notebook, to see if it worked. I also have tried exporting to .csv, and I also only get one result. I tried putting it inside but same result.

Comment: Is it 1000 iterations with the same result?

Comment: @Yusufsn So company_name = company_name.append(container.a.text) ? I then get "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: @AtleKristiansen Each product is unique.

Comment: To use `company_name.append()` you have to create list `company_name = []`

Comment: No, just put `company_name.append(container.a.text)` without assignment to a variable.

Comment: if you get only one result when you use `print()` inside `for` loop then maybe `findAll` can find only one thing. Check `len(containers)`. If page use JavaScript to add elements on page then you may not get all elements with beautifulsoup/requests because beautifulsoup/requests doesn't run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control real web browser which runs JavaScript.

Comment: it is always good idea to add url in question so we could see this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables `product_name`, `product_number`, `category` can keep only one value - last value from loop.

So you can use `print()` inside loop to see values

```
import csv

f = open(filename, 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

# header
csv_writer.writerow( ["Product Name", "Product number", "Category"] ) 

for container in containers:
    product_name = container.a.text
    product_number = container.div.text
    category = container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip()

    # single row 
    csv_writer.writerow( [product_name, product_number, category] ) 

    print("product_name:", product_name)
    print("product_number:", product_number)
    print("category: ", category)

f.close()
```

Or you have to create list and use `append()` to add values to list

```
product_name = []
product_number = []
category = []

for container in containers:
    product_name.append( container.a.text )
    product_number.append( container.div.text )
    category.append( container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip() )

#--- later ---

print("product_name:", product_name)
print("product_number:", product_number)
print("category: ", category)    


f = open(filename, 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

# header
csv_writer.writerow( ["Product Name", "Product number", "Category"] ) 

for a, b, c in zip(product_name, product_number, category):
    # single row 
    csv_writer.writerow( [a, b, c] ) 

f.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also keep it as list with dictionaries

```
all_items = []    

for container in containers:
    item = {
        'product_name': container.a.text,
        'product_number': container.div.text,
        'category': container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip(),
    }
    all_items.append(item)

# --- later ---

f = open(filename, 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

# header
csv_writer.writerow( ["Product Name", "Product number", "Category"] ) 

for item in all_items:
    print("product_name:", item['product_name'])
    print("product_number:", item['product_number'])
    print("category: ", item['category'])    

    # single row 
    csv_writer.writerow( [item['product_name'], item['product_number'], item['category']] ) 

f.close()
```

Comment: When I try option one, I only get one result. When I try option two, I get "NameError: name 'append' is not defined". I guess I need to read up on .append?

Comment: I got second example to create third and I forgot to remove `append()`. Now it is corrected. If you get one result in frist version then you may have wrong indentions - `print()` has to be inside `for` - or `findAll` can find only one element on page.

Comment: The third example only returns one result. The second example works and prints all, but now it's not exporting to my .csv. I was using ```filename = "Products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Name, Number, Category\n"
f.write(headers)```, which I assume I have to change now since I'm using .append?

Comment: open file before `for` loop , export every row inside `for` loop and close it after `for`loop.

Comment: all version should display all values. If you get only one then maybe problem is with `findAll` or page somtimes has only one element.

Comment: if you still have problem then better put full code in question. With url. Or create new question on new page and you will have more space for code, description, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192835/discussion-between-pythonfisher-and-furas).

Comment: That worked great! Now I need to learn how to re-write ```f.write(company_name + "," + booth_number + "," + categories + "\n")``` so I don't get a "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Comment: you do it wrong way - now you have lists so you have to do it in loop - to write every row separatelly. As I said before you could do it direclty in existng loop and then you don't have to create lists. But you should rather use module `csv` and it will add comma between elements. And it will add `"` if it will be needed.

Comment: see changes in examples.

Comment: Thanks. I started a new question because I realized this was getting off topic.